# CORS ORIGIN Error in React App that uses S3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I've been working on a project that client should upload a file into a Cloud Storage with AWS.
My app was written with ReactJS and I decided to upload the file directly from client side to Cloud Storage. I've built the app and deployed it to server. (Here is the link [raymon-tech.ir](https://raymon-tech.ir))
But It returns

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://kamal-archive.s3.ir-thr-at1.arvanstorage.com/aaa.js?uploads'
> from origin 'https://raymon-tech.ir' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
> does not have HTTP ok status.

error.
If I disable CORS of my browser, it works fine.

UPDATE:

I use S3 Browser for config the Bucket Policy and CORS Configuration.
Here's my configs:

CORS Configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>Accept-Ranges</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>Content-Encoding</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>Content-Range</ExposeHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and
Bucket Policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetBucketCORS",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::raysa/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I changed them recently but nothing happend.

Comment: you'll need to configure cors access on the server

Comment: Cross-Post: Posted my answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370716/upload-into-s3-by-reversing-nginx/66375344#66375344

Answer (score 3):

If you need to upload files directly from your front-end app to S3 bucket, please make sure you add those to the bucket's CORS policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "Accept-Ranges",
            "Content-Encoding",
            "Content-Length ",
            "Content-Range"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Comment: does this handle OPTIONS pre-flights? since there is an OPTIONS pre-flight occuring

Comment: I use S3 browser for config the CORS Configuration and Bucket Policy.

Comment: @AliEsmailpor Have you set CORS configuration there?

Comment: Yes I did it like I wrote in Question. Is that correct?

Comment: OPTIONS is not accepted as AllowedMethods. I also had similar issue when I tried to get an S3 object via AWS SDK JS. I had to add POST to the allowedMethods so that the preflight request does not give CORS error.