# Upload into S3 by reversing Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-s3

I have a Bucket that I can easily upload my files into that by NodeJS. But unfortunately, I can't directly upload my files with ReactJS. It returns CORS error when I try.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://test_bucket.s3.ir-thr-at1.arvanstorage.com/temp.png?uploads'
> from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
> does not have HTTP ok status.

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477189/cors-origin-error-in-react-app-that-uses-s3) but I didn't get any result.

Now, I'm using Nginx for proxying with my backend. Is that possible to proxy directly from my ReactJS to S3 Bucket by Nginx?

Comment: Same answer then in the other posting. I have done this with S3. In case the Bucket is still public you should fix the CORS settings to make it work. What is handling the upload part? Do you have a backend service handling it? Or do you really have the API Key and Secret in your ReactJS App?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried a lot. What is your suggestion for fixing CORS setting? Have you tested in something like React directly?

Comment: No - because I would never ever share my API Key and Secret with the World in client side js code. I have always a Backend-Service handling the Upload for me.

Comment: As the answer states in the other question, you need to configure cors. This has to be done from your s3 service provider. Most major providers have documentation on how to enable it. If the provider you are using doesn't document CORS settings, I would advise switching providers perhaps

Comment: Dear @TimoStark yes you're right. I did it too. But my problem is I can't use axios for uploading large files. Because of poor network speed and axios timeout. Am I right?

Comment: Dear @AbrahamLabkovsky yes I've got suspicious too about you said. I told them but they told me nothing about it. If it was true I can do what I said with Nginx? Because in my country there is no more provider.

Comment: You are mixing up things. NGINX is not a provider. Its a webserver or proxy in your case. Just proxying the upload to S3 will not solve the problems of having key and secret stored client side. AXIOS is a tool! has nothing todo with an upload to s3 in general. Use this as a reference. This will work for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader

Comment: I didn't say that Nginx is a provider. Look what I said. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer. Not really. You are mixing up things. First of all

**DO NOT STORE / SHARE YOUR AWS API KEY AND SECRET WITH THE ENTIRE WORLD**

Having the API Key and Secret in your ReactJS App will make it readable to others!! You do not want this! Trust me!

In your case I would recomand using a client side component for your ReactJS App talking to a small lightweight backend service holding your secrets.

A quite usefull implementation for ReactJS and NodeJS using Express is this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader

The Backend-Service can be proxied by NGINX. Of course. Make sure the ´sign-url´ is reachable from your frontend code.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader#server-side

This will work for you. Pretty sure.

Comment: Where exactly I mixed them up? I told you I did that in server side and it's OK but not in large files. There are some ways to hide your KEY. That's not problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You create a backend application (like described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader#server-side) and host it on your server. How do you "hide" your key in a client-side js file?

Comment: Please look what I said above if you want to help. No I didn't do like your link. I did that another way (I send my files by axios to my back-end and then I send them to s3 by NodeJS). By the way, in another projects I already get my Keys from back-end by sending a request. In this way It won't be necessary to keep your Keys in Client-Side. For another time, that's not my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/jamescmartinez/nginx-s3-upload/blob/master/config/nginx.conf

Comment: got it. Just was confused by: ` I have a Bucket that I can easily upload my files into that by NodeJS. But unfortunately, I can't directly upload my files with ReactJS. It returns CORS error when I try.` That sounds like you try to upload the fies directly from react. So but long story short. Nginx alone will not help. Where do you see the cors issue? Does the connection from your FE app to your nodejs app show a cors error? In this case NGINX can help. If you want to put functionality in NGINX Lua will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, in this project, I see CORS error in console of FE app if I want to directly send my files from ResctJS to s3. I mentioned that in my another question.

Comment: In another project I use back-end for handling this and without any problem (except large files) it works. That the link you sent can complete it perfectly. But I really want to upload my files from ReactJS to s3 directly.

Comment: Allright. Now its clear. Please update your question here and share the exact configuration you have for used for the nginx-s3-proxy. is your server_name for the s3-proxy `https://test_bucket.s3.ir-thr-at1.arvanstorage.com`? If so add this to you nginx config for your s3 proxy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747209/nginx-blocked-by-cors-policy/60747893#60747893

Comment: Thank you dear Timo. Could you please let me do it tomorrow? I’m not in good place now. In addition, I’ve not used s3 proxy yet.

Comment: Dear Timo could you please give me exact configuration of Nginx?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229236/discussion-between-timo-stark-and-ali-esmailpor).